# Compute a value that uses result from previous row

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to compute a value for every row that is a function of the current row, and the result from the previous row. The specific function I have is:

`v(i) = k(i) * v(i-1)`

This doesn't work, but the general idea is something like

`SELECT k * LAST_VALUE(cum) as cum from numbers`

or the pseudocode:

```
prev_val = 10
for r in rows 
  prev_val = prev_val + prev_val * r.k
  r.v = prev_val
```

Here's a sample input table:

| v | k |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 5 |

And the desired output:

| v | k |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 12 | 2 |
| 72 | 5 |

The value of v in each row is computed by multiplying the value computed for the previous row by (k+1). e.g. 1 * (3+1) = 4, 4*(2+1) = 12.

Comment: provide sample  and expected result

Comment: Added an example with expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be as easy as below example

```
select *, 1 * exp(sum(ln(1+k)) over(order by i)) as calculated_v
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

Note; you must have some column that will define order of calculation  - so I added column `i` for that exact reason - but it can be column of any type  - -like date or timestamp, etc.

[image]